# How do I genericize Yew web request

Tags: generics, rust, yew

I'm trying to figure out how to make this web request code from the yew examples generic for Deserialize types and variants of an enum.

```rust
// Deserialize type
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct TagsResponse {
    tags: Vec<String>,
}

// Enum variants
pub enum Msg {
    TagsLoaded(Result<TagsResponse, Error>),
    TagsLoadError,
}

// Working non-generic inline code
let callback = model.link.send_back(
    //       want to make TagsResponse generic ⤵ 
    move |response: Response<Json<Result<TagsResponse, Error>>>| {
        let (meta, Json(data)) = response.into_parts();
        if meta.status.is_success() {
         //  ↓ and be able to pass in an enum value
            Msg::TagsLoaded(data)
        } else {
         //  ↓ and be able to pass in an enum value
            Msg::TagsLoadError
        }
    },
);
let request = Request::get(format!("{}{}", API_ULR, "tags"))
    .body(Nothing)
    .unwrap();
let task = model.fetch_service.fetch(request, callback);
model.fetch_task.push(task);
```

Here is about as far as I've gotten which seems pretty close but I've gotten into kind of a loop following the compiler:

```rust
fn remote_get<T: 'static>(
    fetch_service: &mut FetchService,
    link: &mut ComponentLink<Model>,
    success_msg: fn(Result<T, Error>) -> Msg,
    error_msg: Msg,
) -> FetchTask
where
    for<'de> T: serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    let callback = link.send_back(move |response: Response<Json<Result<T, Error>>>| {
        let (meta, Json(data)) = response.into_parts();
        if meta.status.is_success() {
            success_msg(data)
        } else {
            error_msg
        }
    });
    let request = Request::get(format!("{}{}", API_ULR, "articles?limit=10&offset=0"))
        .body(Nothing)
        .unwrap();
    fetch_service.fetch(request, callback)
}
```

with the call site:

```
let task = remote_get(
    &mut self.fetch_service,
    &mut self.link,
    Msg::TagsLoaded,
    Msg::TagsLoadError,
);
self.fetch_task.push(task);
```

produces:

```
    |
598 |     error_msg: Msg,
    |     --------- captured outer variable
...
608 |             error_msg
    |             ^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured variable in an `Fn` closure
```

Strangely, if I remove error_msg from the arguments list and simply hard code `Msg::TagsLoadError` it will compile but then the request doesn't run. ‍♂️

Comment: Please, provide [mre] so we can download it / copy & paste it. There will be higher chance that someone will help if you do it. For example - I've never used Yew -> no idea what I should put into the Cargo.toml. There's no single `use` statement -> no idea from where are these types coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ComponentLink::send_back()`](https://docs.rs/yew/0.8.0/yew/html/struct.ComponentLink.html#method.send_back) expects a `Fn` closure. However, your closure is consuming a captured variable, namely `error_msg`, so it can only be called once. That makes your closure implement `FnOnce` instead of `Fn`, so it cannot be used there.

A simpler way to see this is:

```rust
struct Foo;

fn call(f: impl Fn() -> Foo) {}

fn test(x: Foo) {
    let cb = move || x;
    call(cb);
}
```

The complete error message is somewhat clearer:

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:14
  |
6 |     let cb = move || x;
  |              ^^^^^^^^-
  |              |       |
  |              |       closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `x` out of its environment
  |              this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
7 |     call(cb);
  |     ---- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
```

This makes sense; what would happen if you wrote `call(cb)` several times? Remember that `Foo` is not copyable nor clonable.

Precisely, the easiest solution is to make your type cloneable, so it can be reused:

```rust
let cb = move || {
    x.clone()
};
```

And it works!

If you don't want the cost of the clone, you could add some workaround, such as passing a function that returns an error or some kind of reference counted pointer. For example:

```
struct Foo;

fn call(f: impl Fn() -> Foo) {}

fn test(build_x: impl Fn() -> Foo) {
    let cb = move || build_x();
    call(cb);
}
```

This works because `build_x` is a `Fn`, not a `FnOnce`, so it is not consumed when used, that is, you can call it as many times as you want.

Another workaround without callbacks is to use an `Option` and consume it by using `Option::take`. This replaces it with `None`, and from the borrow checker's point of view the value goes on existing. However you need a `RefCell` because otherwise you would be mutating a captured variable and converting your closure into a `FnMut`.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
struct Foo;

fn call(f: impl Fn() -> Foo) {}

fn test(x: Foo) {
    let ox = RefCell::new(Some(x));
    let cb = move || ox.borrow_mut().take().unwrap();
    call(cb);
}
```

**UPDATE to the last option**

Do not use a `RefCell` when a simple `Cell` will do. And `Cell` has a `take` member function that makes this code simpler:

```
use std::cell::Cell;
struct Foo;

fn call(f: impl Fn() -> Foo) {}

fn test(x: Foo) {
    let ox = Cell::new(Some(x));
    let cb = move || ox.take().unwrap();
    call(cb);
}
```